# Unterschied zwischen ansagen, ankündigen und durchsagen

Tags: difference

Ich habe keine Ahnung was die Unterschied ist und jedes mal wenn ich einer dieser Wörte nutze, kriege ich das Gefühl, dass es falsch ist. Sind die folgende Sätze richtig?

„Wir haben eine Ansage - die Firma wurde gekauft und der neue Inhaber wird bald mit Ihnen alle Gespräche zur Übernahme führen“

„Ich würde gern was ansagen: wir sind seit mehrere Jahren zusammen und haben uns entschieden zu heiraten“

„Wir kündigen das Geburt unserer Tochter an“

„Bitte hören Sie alle Durchsagen der kommenden Minuten“

„Sobald wir mehr über die Lage wissen, sagen wir es durch“

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34095/different-words-for-announcement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Versuchen wir's mal:

**Durchsagen:** Hier ist tpyischerweise ein bestimmter (elektrischer?) Kommunikationskanal im Spiel, zum Beispiel das Lautsprechersystem einer Schule oder eines Bahnhofs. - Natürlich kann es in der Praxis auch vorkommen, dass ein solches (elektrisches) System nicht vorhanden ist, sondern andere Wege benutzt werden. Wichtig ist jedenfalls der Aspekt der Mitteilung an eine größere Menge von Leuten. Typischerweise würde man bei einer *Durchsage* die Leute, zu denen man spricht, auch nicht sehen. Oft ist auch eine Form von Hierarchie im Spiel. (Dies ergibt sich allerdings schon aus der Verfügung über den nur in eine Richtung laufenden Kommunikationskanal.) Außerdem haben Durchsagen typischerweise den Charakter des Unvorhergesehenen, Situativen.<sup>1</sup>

**Ankündigen:** Jegliche Form von Information zu Dingen, die in der Zukunft liegen. Der Kommunikationskanal spielt hier keine Rolle. Du kannst mit einer Durchsage (übers Lautsprechersystem) die Ankündigung machen, dass die Schule morgen wegen großer Hitze geschlossen bleibt. Es spielt auch keine Rolle, ob du nur zu einer Person sprichst oder zu vielen. Du kannst deiner Freundin ankündigen, dass du mit ihr Schluss machen wirst.<sup>2</sup>

**Ansagen:** In der Grundform: Jemand stellt sich vor ein Publikum und macht eine kurze Mitteilung. (Eine lange Rede wäre keine Ansage mehr.)  Oft (aber nicht zwangsläufig) hat der Inhalt der Ansage etwas mit der Zukunft zu tun. Auch ein Sprecher im Fernsehen, der die nächste Sendung ankündigt, macht eine Ansage.

Oder kurz:

Eine **Ansage** (kurze Mitteilung an ein Publikum) kann auch mittels einer **Durchsage** (über einen Einbahn-Kommunikationskanal) erfolgen und eine **Ankündigung** (für etwas, das in der Zukunft liegt) beinhalten.

---

<sub>1) Entsprechend ist die Ansage (siehe dort) eines Fernsehsprechers keine Durchsage. Mir scheint, der Grund ist, dass wir vom Fernsehsprecher *erwarten*, dass er uns etwas mitteilt. Eine Durchsage hat dagegen den Charakter des Unerwarteten, Ungeplanten, Irregulären, Situativen. Der Fernsehsprecher kann zwar auch eine Durchsage machen, aber dann müsste es etwas sein, das nicht zum erwartbaren Programm gehört.</sub>

<sub>2) Das wäre in diesem Fall außerdem ein *performativer Akt*.</sub>